# Navigating through different pages with onClick & radio buttons - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, radio-button, react-router-dom

*Using react-router-dom and react.js

I have two different set of radio buttons. One set has 2 buttons while the other set has 3. I want to navigate to a new page whenever a user clicks on two buttons (one in each set). We have a total of six different outcomes, therefore 6 different pages to navigate to. It seems to work fine but with one problem: it only works when we click on a button for a second time. Example: Clicking on "Messages" & "Global" doesn't work initially and doesn't do anything but then if we click on a different button, then it navigates to the initial set of buttons we clicked.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you.

````
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function DisplayHomeOptions() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({ location: "", selector: "" })

    function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
            }
        })
    }

    function test() {
        return (
            formData.location === "National" && formData.selector === "Polls" ? navigate("/np") :
                formData.location === "Global" && formData.selector === "Questions" ? navigate("/gq") :
                    formData.location === "Global" && formData.selector === "Polls" ? navigate("/gp") :
                        formData.location === "National" && formData.selector === "Messages" ? navigate("/nm") :
                            formData.location === "National" && formData.selector === "Questions" ? navigate("/nq") :
                                formData.location === "Global" && formData.selector === "Messages" ? navigate("/gm") : null
        )
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Option #1</legend>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="location"
                    value="Global"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onClick={test}
                />

                <label htmlFor="Global">Global</label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="location"
                    value="National"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onClick={test}
                />
                <label htmlFor="National">National</label>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Option #2</legend>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selector"
                    value="Messages"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onClick={test}


                />
                <label htmlFor="Messages">Messages</label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selector"
                    value="Questions"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onClick={test}

                />
                <label htmlFor="Questions">Questions</label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selector"
                    value="Polls"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onClick={test}
                />
                <label htmlFor="Polls">Polls</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    )
}```
````

Comment: You've fixed the issue, thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that React state updates aren't immediately processed, they are enqueued and asynchronously processed later. The `formData` state update from `handleChange` is not yet available when `test` function is called as the same time.

## Solution

It seems you want the act of navigation to be an effect of selecting from the radio buttons. Move the `test` function logic into an `useEffect` hook to issue the imperative navigation.

Example:

```
export default function DisplayHomeOptions() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    location: "",
    selector: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const { location, selector } = formData;
    switch (true) {
      case location === "National" && selector === "Polls":
        navigate("/np");
        break;

      case location === "Global" && selector === "Questions":
        navigate("/gq");
        break;

      case location === "Global" && selector === "Polls":
        navigate("/gp");
        break;

      case location === "National" && selector === "Messages":
        navigate("/nm");
        break;

      case location === "National" && selector === "Questions":
        navigate("/nq");
        break;

      case location === "Global" && selector === "Messages":
        navigate("/gm");
        break;

      default:
      // ignore
    }
  }, [formData]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
      };
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option #1</legend>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="location"
          value="Global"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <label htmlFor="Global">Global</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="location"
          value="National"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="National">National</label>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option #2</legend>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="selector"
          value="Messages"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="Messages">Messages</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="selector"
          value="Questions"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="Questions">Questions</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="selector"
          value="Polls"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="Polls">Polls</label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  );
}
```

An optimization may be to declare a Map of target paths from the `location` and `selector` values as keys.

```
const navTarget = {
  National: {
    Messages: "/nm",
    Polls: "/np",
    Questions: "/nq",
  },
  Global: {
    Messages: "/gm",
    Polls: "/gp",
    Questions: "/gq",
  }
}
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
  const { location, selector } = formData;
  if (location && selector) {
    const target = navTarget[location][selector];
    if (target) {
      navigate(target);
    }
  }
}, [formData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` event fires before `onChange` event. To account for this, you could move navigation into the `onChange` event handler.